# brew install certbot -> No available formula

Tags: homebrew

Every Let's Encrypt tutorial starts with installing certbot:

`brew install certbot`

When I do this, I get a:

`Error: No available formula for certbot`

So what is wrong?

Comment: have you tried `brew update` first?

Comment: Yep that helped, thanks. Stupid I didn't do that first....

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do when you get a `No available formula for X` is to run `brew update` and try again. A few months ago Homebrew got an auto-update feature that should reduce these kind of errors.